# Automating a webgl game with selenium and opencv

Tags: python, selenium, opencv

i have been having trouble with this website, I'm trying to automate a game that runs on webgl, but things are wierd.

I did all the setup with selenium, working with DOM's, but now it came to the canvas part, I'm taking screenshots of the website with selenium and template matching with opencv.

The opencv does its job and finds the image I'm looking for, but the problem is selenium, I pass on the coordinates for it to click and its way off, around 100 pixels off.
I know its off, because i tried to get the element.location of a button in that page, and its completely off.

Anyone ever faced this problem?
I'm thinking that its something to do with how the page is setup, but I'm not sure.
I tried to calculate the offset, by subtracting the actual position of the element and what opencv tells me and it works, for the button, but it seems like its bound to fail.

this is the website: https://app.bombcrypto.io/webgl/index.html
The element I used to test the offset is the full screen button, opencv finds it perfectly, but selenium gives a location which is offset to the top and left

```
button = self.driver.find_element_by_id('unity-fullscreen-button')
```

gives the location x: 1210 y: 637

opencv gives the location x:1513 y: 797

[image]
the white box near the text bombcrypto is what opencv finds, and the black box is the location selenium gives

```
   action = ActionChains(self.driver)
   action.move_by_offset(x, y)
   action.click()
   action.perform()
```

I'm using ActionChains to perform the clicks, when i try to calculate the offset and modify the coordinates given by opencv, it works for the button, but for the content inside the canvas it fails.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and the relevant HTML

Comment: if you use moveToElement(canvasElement) it should move to the top/left... the "click()" will click at the current location... but click(webelement) will click in the center of the webelement. Hopefully with opencv you can return location relative to the canvas... then moveToOffset using those x/y coords after moveToElement should get you there.  Then use .click().

Comment: @pcalkins did not work, one thing which i find odd also, is that element.screenshot_as_png, shrinks the elements, it seems like it shrinks as much as the click is being offset

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the canvas element works, but in this page, if you leave the style empty, the canvas will expand until your pc burns.

Having that in mind, i set a `width` in the style and removed all the styling on the container div

i setup the canvas size this way

```
def resize_game(self):
        self.driver.execute_script('document.bgColor = "black";')
        self.driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("unity-canvas").id = "game";')
        self.driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("unity-footer").style = "display: none;"')
        self.driver.execute_script(
            'document.getElementById("unity-container").id = "container"')
        self.driver.execute_script(
            'document.getElementById("game").setAttribute("width", 256);')
        self.driver.execute_script(
            'document.getElementById("game").setAttribute("height", 192);')
        self.driver.execute_script(
            'document.getElementById("game").style = "width: 256px"')
```

still, when i take screenshots with

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
```

the canvas size changes

it changes to `320px 240px`
why? not really sure, but this gave me a solution, since the canvas is now in the corner, i can just crop the image and resize it.

That's what i did, and it works.
Another solution is to

```
canvas = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//canvas')
img = canvas.screenshot_as_png
```

But doing this flickers the page, since every time you do this, the element changes size to the correct size which is set in css.
Its a valid solution which does not require rescaling the image, but the flickering was too annoying for me.